# How to access a C_POINTER in a MemoryLayout using Java Panama FFI

Tags: java, ffi, project-panama

Using the FFI preview in JDK 16, I have this memory layout:

```
class FfiTest {
    static GroupLayout layout = MemoryLayout.ofStruct(
        C_INT.withName("someInt"),
        MemoryLayout.ofPaddingBits(32), // So the following pointer is aligned at 64 bits
        C_POINTER.withName("somePtr")
    );
}
```

I then receive a pointer to such a structure in a callback from native code:

```
public static void someCallback(MemoryAddress address) {
    try (MemorySegment seg = address.asSegmentRestricted(FfiTest.layout.byteSize())) {                

        // Works: fetching int from native structure, correct value is returned
        VarHandle intHandle = FfiTest.layout.varHandle(int.class, MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("someInt"));
        int intResult = (int) vh.get(seg);

        // Does not work: get the pointer as a MemoryAddress, fatal JVM crash with Hotspot log
        VarHandle badPtrHandle = FfiTest.layout.varHandle(MemoryAddress.class, MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("somePtr"));

        // Works: get the pointer as a long, correct value is returned
        VarHandle goodPtrHandle = FfiTest.layout.varHandle(long.class, MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("somePtr"));
        long longResult = (long) goodPtrHandle.get(seg);
    }
}
```

An exception is thrown inside the JDK code in `jdk.internal.foreign.Utils`:

```
    public static void checkPrimitiveCarrierCompat(Class<?> carrier, MemoryLayout layout) {
        checkLayoutType(layout, ValueLayout.class);
        if (!isValidPrimitiveCarrier(carrier))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported carrier: " + carrier); // Throws this exception, carrier has the value MemoryAddress
        if (Wrapper.forPrimitiveType(carrier).bitWidth() != layout.bitSize())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Carrier size mismatch: " + carrier + " != " + layout);
    }
```

According to the Panama documentation, the Java carrier for a `C_POINTER` is supposed to be `MemoryAddress`, but that does not work here.

So is it correct to use longs for accessing such pointers? Or something else?

Comment: In short - you have to use `long` and then adapt the resulting `VarHandle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Johannes points out in the comments, [`MemoryHandles::asAddressVarHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/jdk.incubator.foreign/jdk/incubator/foreign/MemoryHandles.html) can be used to adapt the `long` handle you have to accept and return a `MemoryAddress`:

```
VarHandle goodPtrHandle = FfiTest.layout.varHandle(long.class, MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("somePtr"));
long longResult = (long) goodPtrHandle.get(seg);
VarHandle addrHandle = MemoryHandles.asAddressVarHandle(goodPtrHandle);
MemoryAddress addrResult = (MemoryAddress) addrHandle.get(seg);
```